# ASP.Net MVC: Check if URL is Authorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, authorization, roles, routes

I'd like to simply check from a Controller whether another URL is authorized.

So for example, I'd like to call into a Controller like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IsUrlAuthorized(string url)
{
    bool isAuthorized = // What do I put here?
    return Json(isAuthorized);
}
```

So I'd like to know what I could call to check on whether the current user is authorized for the passed-in URL or not. I'm guessing the answer has something to do with Routes, which sit a little bit outside MVC?

This is a somewhat similar question but not quite the same thing:
[ASP.NET MVC. Check if user is authorized from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666270/asp-net-mvc-check-if-user-is-authorized-from-javascript)

Since the user may or may not be authorized in general, but may not have the right permissions or role assignments to see a specific URL.

Ideas?

Update: I use standard MVC authorization attributes to lock down my app, so I'll just give an example of what that looks like here. In MVC Routes map to Controllers. A single method on a Controller can be restricted to one or more Roles:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "User, Moderator")]
    public ActionResult ListRecentPosts()
    {
        . . .
    }
}
```

Or, an entire Controller can be restricted to one or more roles:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
. . .
```

The actual URL that any of these controller methods responds to is based on a default mapping in a standard MVC app:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But, you can be nice to your users and make URLs guessable by adding a lot more Routes - as a result, a Controller method can have many names that point to it. You can't just assume and infer the controller name from the URL (even if it maps out that way for half the URLs in the site).

So presumably I either need a way to ask the Routing engine directly whether a URL is authorized for the current user, or a 2-step of asking the Routing engine for which Controller and Method, then ask if those are authorized - hopefully not by using Reflection and matching Roles directly as that again would appear to assume too much.

Update 2: The way this came up is I have an Account strip at the top of my app. Its state can change by selecting one of several accounts you're authorized as. Depending on where you are in the app, the account you chose might have authorization to view this page - and you might be in the middle of filling out a form you don't want to lose. So the naive approach - just refresh when they pick another account - is harmful, and a waste of the user's time even if there is no form and they're just reading a page that's all text.

While that convenience to the user is nice, the user is going to fairly assume that pages they can't see as a user who shouldn't have permission really are denied (and, it would be harmful to leave them on a page that's forbidden - actions taken from it will fail). So I need to know whether to redirect away based on their new permissions.

One of the things I love about .Net is the way many of its best libraries decompose so well, so you can easily recompose things that are part of its normal functionality, or a new twist. Both the Routing module and MVC appear to be very well constructed, so I have to suspect this can be done.

The cheap hack is to ensure that my authorization module returns a consistent redirect status code when a user isn't authorized, and when the user changes their account in the account strip, fire 2 AJAX calls: One to change account, and then a second to the current page over AJAX just to check the HTTP Status Code. 200 OK means leave the page as is, Redirect means follow the redirect. Obviously this is a little ugly, involves an extra HTTP call, creates a false hit in the logs, and makes an assumption about how authorization is handled across the app.

There could be a secondary concern - the page might be authorized, but just change how it works or looks. This particular app has no change in look based on account (besides the account strip itself), and I can handle functionality changes by just providing a custom event that forms listen to - they can reload any relevant data from the server in response to it.

Comment: where are these right permissions are stored

Comment: I'll expand my question to give examples of how I currently define permissions (it's standard MVC stuff)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using UrlAuthorization.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal only works if you're only using URL authorization. But for MVC using Routing, we highly recommend that you don't use URL authorization to secure an app.

Instead, we recommend using Authorization attributes on the controller class. The reason is there could be multiple URLs that call the same controller action. It's always better to secure the resource at the the resource and not just at the entry ways.

In this particular case, you'd have to get an instance of the controller given the URL. THat's a little tricky as you'll basically have to run the MVC pipeline from the point where you have the URL to the point where you have the controller. It's possible, but seems heavyweight.

I wonder if there isn't a better and simpler way to accomplish your goals. What is it you're really trying to do?

UPDATE: Based on your scenario, it sounds like this is an initial check just for UI purposes. Perhaps all you need to do is make an asynchronous Ajax request to the URL and check the HTTP Status code. If it's a 401 status code, you know the user is not authorized. That seems like the safest bet.

Comment: I'll expand on the question a bit more to explain goals.

Answer (score -1):

How about UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal method.

[UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal Method (System.Web.Security)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.security.urlauthorizationmodule.checkurlaccessforprincipal.aspx)

Comment: Never tried this, but would it work for MVC where authorization doesn't ride the typical url-mapped-to-file funk-schwa of ASP.NET but rather needs to compute the route and figure out which controller and action is in play?

Comment: create default mvc3 solution, and Home/Index.cshtml write @UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal("~/Account/ChangePassword", User, "GET").allways true! ummmm,sorry dont work.

Comment: UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal not check Authorize attribute...

Comment: Do note that there's a security demand on that method meaning this call won't work in Medium Trust, assuming that's important to you at all. :)