# How to check ASP.NET C# Request.IsAuthenticated in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, request

At the page load I want to check `Request.IsAuthenticated`. How can I do it through javascript. 
The code below shows how I did it in asp.net c#?

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
     Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/5666409/4513879

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC. Check if user is authorized from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666270/asp-net-mvc-check-if-user-is-authorized-from-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC then you can do like following.

```
 <script>
     var isRequestAuthenticated=' @Request.IsAuthenticated';
 </script>
```

Else if you are using normal ASP.NET Web forms

```
 <script>
     var isRequestAuthenticated='<%=Request.IsAuthenticated%>';
 </script>
```

Now you can use that variable to check whether this request is authenticated or not.

Comment: Try asp.net webform. I have given both options read it carefully

Comment: I am using a webform were there is no code behind. All the functionalities in javascript file. It tried your code in page load of Javascript but it always returns true regardless whether logged in or logged out.

Comment: On the webforms example, C# will render "False". And because non-empty strings are truthy in javascript, writing `if(isRequestAuthenticated){foo();}` will execute `foo()` if `isRequestAuthenticated` == `"False"`. I took out the single quotes and added `.ToString().ToLower()`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function foo(){
            if('@Request.IsAuthenticated' === 'True') {
                // your implementation for authenticated users go here

            }
            else{
                // your implementation for not authenticated users....
                //e.g. alert('You must be logged in to do bla bla bla');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By JavaScript, I assume that you mean using AJAX so that the value is read directly into your JavaScript.

```
Response.Write(Request.IsAuthenticated ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```

This will return "TRUE" if true, "FALSE" if false. Put this into a method that only your AJAX function calls.